# Sucessfuly sent from Android App, but the Post is not shown on facebook timeline

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I'm trying to post to a friend timeline form an android application, by using the below method, Although, I'm getting a post id , and no error or exception is shown , the post is not there on the user timeline, unless the user is my own timeline.
The post is shown fine only when I post to my own timeline.
Appreciating any idea and help.
Thanks..

```
private void publishFeedDialog(GraphUser user) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("to",user.getId() );//user.getId());
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because your application is in sandbox mode. In this mode, only users involved in the development of the application are able to see content generated by the app. [Read about it more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/)

Comment: You are 150% right ;) .. Thanks for the answer

Comment: my app is not in "sandbox mode" still this thing happening,
getting postId also still not appearing on timeline,
even I have changed data like put simple message, still no luck